# Check the first line of bash script and skip the script if # is available

Tags: bash, awk

i want to check the first line of the script and if the first line is a # the script should not run I came up with this not sure if its the right syntax and login p=cat -n1 /tmp/abc | awk '{print $1} if [ $p = "#" ]; then exit 0 fi

Comment: Please format your code readably. I can't even tell where the code begins -- is `login` part of it?

Comment: You can't access shell variables inside an `awk` script like that.

Answer (score 3):

To assign the output of a program to a variable you use `variable$(command)`.

But you don't need to execute a program like `awk` to get the first line of a file, just use

```
read -r p </tmp/abc
```

Your `awk` command was returning the first field of *every* line, not just the first line.

You should always put variable in quotes unless you're sure you need to allow word splitting and/or wildcard expansion of the result. Since the first line of the file might contain whitespace, this is important in your script.

```
read -r p </tmp/abc
if [ "$p" = "#" ]
then exit 0
fi
```

You could also use

to read the first line of the file into a variable.

Comment: I'd suggest using `read -r p </tmp/abc` rather than a command substitution invoking an external tool. Maybe `read -n 1 -r p </tmp/abc` if we only want the very first character.

Comment: so you saying it should be this way


p=$(read -n 1 -r p </tmp/abc)
if [ $p = "#" ];then
exit 0
fi

Comment: @user8185098 No, it should just be `read -r p </tmp/abc`, there's no need for `p=` around that.

Comment: `read` sets the variable you give it, you don't need a separate assignment.

Comment: so if i give 

read -r p </tmp/abc --> it will read the first character of the file abc and will check if its a #   ?

Comment: No, it will read the first *line* of the file and check if it's `#`. That's what you said in the question.

Comment: If you just want the first character you can use `read -r -n 1 p </tmp/abc`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the first line with `head`, then `test` it to see if it matches the `#` character:

```
if [ x"$(head -n1 $pathtoscript)" == x"#" ] ;then
   echo "Won't run"
   exit
fi
```

Comment: Running two separate external commands with a pipe between them is *way* less efficient than just doing this internal to your already-running shell interpreter. `read -r line <"$pathtoscript"; if [[ $line = "#"* ]]; then echo "First line starts with a pound"; fi`

Comment: Also, the `$( )` is utterly unnecessary here: It's trying to string-split the output of `grep -q` and execute it as a command; only the fact that there *is no such* output saves it from being a bug, as opposed to a mere inefficency. `if head -n 1 <"$pathtoscript" | grep -q '^#$'; then` is perfectly valid syntax on its own, and more efficient to execute. (Using the redirection so we don't have corner cases with paths that start with dashes and the like).

Comment: totally right @CharlesDuffy, I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: If you care about portability, change `==` to `=`. The `x`s are only needed in 1970s-era (pre-POSIX) shells, unless you're using obsolescent features like `-a` and `-o` (which you aren't). See the relevant standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, noting the `[OB XSI]` notation by those features' specifications, and the lack of any mention of `==` at all.